# How can I find Inclination and Longitude of ascending node for the Moon on JPL's Horizons?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, apollo-13

To answer the bountied question "Puzzler: Precisely what maximum distance from the Earth did the Apollo 13 astronauts achieve? ", I have to know the Inclination and the Longitude of ascending node for the Moon on April 15, 1970 at the time the Apollo 13 crew flew behind it, but on JPL Horizons it seems I'm only able to find Right ascension and Declination.

Or are there table settings with which it is still possible to find them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the default output of HORIZONS is for the Observer Table as this is the most useful to the majority of users. If you change the 'Ephemeris Type' to `Osculating Orbital Elements`, the 'Target Body' to `Moon [Luna]` (can just search for 'Moon', just don't pick the '`Earth-Moon Barycenter`' option from the list) and set the time span to what you want, so that it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of JPL HORIZONS configured to produce orbital elements for the Moon]
then hitting the 'Generate Ephemeris' button will produce the orbital elements for the range you want/have configured. An example of the output is shown below:
[image: Example elements output from JPL HORIZONS for the Moon] Scroll down to the end of the elements output for an explanation of the symbols; I think you want `IN` for the inclination and `OM` for the longitude of the ascending node.

Comment: Great, thank you, this is so important for me that I will start a bounty as soon as I can !